# Snapchat like camera

Tags: ios, xcode, avcapturesession, custom-view, snapchat

Right now, I am making a snapchat like application, I made a custom camera following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=994Hsi1zs6Q), then on the [next video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUTevJAhL3Q) he explains how to take pictures.

My problem is that he takes the picture touching the screen and I want to take a picture with a button, right now the *.xib* looks like this:

[image]

First, I had this issue:

```
    func didPressTakeAnother(){
    if didTakePhoto == true{
        tempImageView.hidden = true
        didTakePhoto = false

    }
    else{
        captureSession?.startRunning()
        didTakePhoto = true
        didPressTakePhoto()

    }
```

because I added a button I changed the func didPressTakePhoto so ii had this popping an error.

[image]

After that, I wanted to test it out, so I commented that piece of code so it builds but the button text doesn't appear and I can't take the picture now.

Any idea on how to make it work?

[here is a paste bin with the code from the video](http://pastebin.com/2Wsc0ZkP)

Comment: That error is asking you to give input for `sender` which in your case is a button on your storyboard. I think you know how to add an @IBAction from the storyboard to your class?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 this is the code i modified http://pastebin.com/XwSMc3ad i already added an IBAction, but i get different errors on that line